# Cannot resolve method when passing a concrete class

Tags: java

Why is this an invalid syntax?
I thought polymorphism will occur in this example.
The shape could be known only in runtime and it should be dispatched to the correct method.
Why won't this work?

```
public class Test {

    public interface Shape {

    }

    static class Circle implements Shape {

    }

    static class Square implements Shape {

    }


    public void foo(Shape shape) {
        Shape s = new Circle();
        bar(s);
    }

    public void bar(Circle c) {

    }

    public void bar(Square s) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using Circle reference instead of Shape:

```
public void foo(Shape shape) {
    Circle s = new Circle();
    bar(s);
}
```

In method `foo` variable `s` is a `Shape` class. And your `bar` methods expect only one of two : Circle or Square.

Your code would work if you create a method that receives a Shape

```
public void bar(Shape c) {

}
```

But because it is missing, the compiler throws an exception.

To above method you could pass references of: Shape, Circle and Square. But then you will end up with a single method for all shapes.

If you know the class only in the runtime, then you need to do some casting:

```
public void foo(Shape shape) {
   Shape s = new Circle();

   if(Circle.class.isInstance(s)){
      bar(Circle.class.cast(s));
   } else if (Square.class.isInstance(s)){
      bar(Square.class.cast(s));
   }
}
```

Comment: I could change the Shape -> Circle, however I only know the concrete class at runtime....

Comment: @delita If that is so, will both methods `void bar(Circle c)` and `public void bar(Square s)` call similar methods are `c` and `s`? Can you provide an outline of what goes into these `bar(Shape s)` methods, so that I can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct polymorphism will occur but at `run-time`. At compile time it only knows the `declaration` type. So there should be the same type in the method argument.

You can change the method like below:

```
public void bar(Shape s) {

  if(s instanceof Circle){

  }else if(s instanceof Square) {

  } 
}
```

Comment: Or add ```bar``` as a method to ```Shape``` and implement in the ```Circle``` and ```Square``` classes